# How to setOnTouchListener for an item in a ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-view

I want to get an item from my ListView and setOnTouchListener for that, the following is my code but I am unable to set it properly.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View selectedView,
                    int position, long id) {

            Log.d("ON ITEM CLICK...", " ON ITEM CLICK... "+ position);

            listView.getChildAt(position).setOnTouchListener(HorizontalListActivity.this);

            ViewHolder viewHolder =(ViewHolder)selectedView.getTag();

            viewHolder.ivThumbnail.setOnTouchListener(HorizontalListActivity.this);

            }
        });
```

The reason I wanted to access the item is that I want to drag it on the screen.

Is there a better way to do what I want?

Comment: try change `listView.getChildAt(position).setOnTouchListener` to `selectedView.setOnTouchListener` or in `getView` method, when init the `ivThumbnail` , using `setOnTouchListener`

Comment: that doesnt work either, onTouch is not fired

Comment: `setOnTouchListener` dont mean trigger the onTouchevent, just set the listener, only next time it be ontouched, will invoke the `OnTouchListner` interface method.

Comment: Ive tried touching it two times, it still doesn't work..

Comment: I've had problems with touch events before and the issue was that the parent view was stealing them so the child never saw them. So in your case the `ListView` is stealing the touch events so the `ListView` elements never get them. Unfortunately I don't have any suggestions for how to fix it.

Comment: can you try this: listview dont set `setOnItemClickListener`, and in your `getView` method in adapter, you set the view which you want to receive event using method `setOnClickListener(...)`, avoid using `setOnTouchListener`.

Comment: How your are creating the list view. I think your extending the Base adapter To creating the List view. So instead of setting the Listener on the List view set the on click listener for the widget that you have put Inside the List view.

Comment: @mayur rahatekar:that doesn't solve the problem either

Comment: @mirroredAbstraction Can you tell which widget your are using Inside the Listview.

Comment: It is a custom widget, but anyways how can we have an touch listener for the items of a any widget?

Comment: @mirroredAbstraction i have face same problem . have u got any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm in the same situation, and have found something that might work, yet I have not had the time to try it out. The basic idea is to dispatch the touch event to the child, like you did, with getChildAt. You listen for touch events in the listview, and simply if you touched the view you are interested in, dispatch the touch event to it to handle it:

```
 MyControl control = ListViews.getChildAt(position));
 control.onTouchEvent(touchEvent);
```

Comment: I've tested approach this successful - for scrolling inside a scrollable view, just dispatch the event to the children (you might also need to use findview to get the appropriate views inside different layouts, depending on what you have... But this definitely works.

Answer (score 0):

I did it like that

```js
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View selectedView,
                                int position, long id) {

            selectedView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            x1 = event.getX();
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            x2 = event.getX();
                            float deltaX = x2 - x1;
                            if (Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE) {
                                if (x2 > x1) {
                                    Toast.makeText(PlayerList.this,"left to right",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                }
                                else {
                                    Toast.makeText(PlayerList.this,"right to left",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            } else {
                                // consider as something else - a screen tap for example
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });


        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).